# unbelievable mistake of searchsorted command in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, command, closest

The command is as follows

```
>>> s = np.array([1, 5, 2, 6, 1])
>>> s.searchsorted(3)
```

Python response is as follows

```
5
```

Is this response really correct?

Comment: `s` has to be sorted.

Comment: The function is behaving as documented. In that sense, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `searchsorted()` function finds the indices where the element could be inserted to peserve the order, so the '5' that the function returns, means that the '3' should be inserted in the index 5 which is at the end, because the array `s` is not in any specific order [in the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is mentioned that the function uses binary seach so at the first step it compares '3' with the element at the middle of `s`, so because 2<3 the function discards the first half of `s` supposing that `s` is in order and so the array left is `[6,1]` and because 6<3<1 doesn´t make sense the function returns the last index.

Comment: Thank you so much, for your complete and useful answer.